# Possibility of rejection in Polish (Poland) PhD programme after finding possible advisor

Tags: phd, application, poland, guaranteed-admissions

This is my first question here so if this has been asked again I am sorry for the duplicate

**Backround**
Recently I contacted a faculty member of a Polish university in order to apply for a PhD position in mathematics. After he asked for my grades, CV, Master Thesis and an opinion letter from my thesis advisor, he told me that he could be my PhD advisor. He also sent me stuff to read and some of his papers to get a grip on the subject. Also I planned a visit in the city and we arranged a meeting there next week.
My grades were not super good, although in most of the subjects that I was interested in I did pretty well. He asked me why my grades were like that and I explained to him that I was working full time while studying in order to make it financially viable (true, working since my BSc years)

**Admission procedure**

A candidate has to send his application in May, I have secured two references from my professors in my home country, and he accepted to take me as a PhD student. A person who makes an application is evaluated in a 20-30 minute interview.

**Question**
My question is, what are the chances of not getting accepted in the PhD programme? Also if someone has an experience from Polish universities, can he/she tell my how strict the process is and what I should expect to confront in the interview?

Comment: I don't think anyone other than said professor will be able to actually answer the question posed here.

Comment: I have not voted to close your question because I think that the specifics regarding Poland are interesting and because most (approximately) similar questions are about the US. However, I suggest that you edit your question, bringing the important part of the question (about Poland and Polish academia) to the fore and moving most of the material about yourself to a section labelled "Background" later.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, I will do that!